# Custom TensorFlow Keras optimizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tf.keras, tensorflow2.x

Suppose I want to write a custom optimizer class that conforms to the `tf.keras` API (using TensorFlow version>=2.0). I am confused about the documented way to do this versus what's done in implementations.

The documentation for `tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer` [states](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3ba8ba551fc371389d184ba3917cfd826bdefd89/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L217-L223),

```
  ### Write a customized optimizer.
  If you intend to create your own optimization algorithm, simply inherit from
  this class and override the following methods:

    - resource_apply_dense (update variable given gradient tensor is dense)
    - resource_apply_sparse (update variable given gradient tensor is sparse)
    - create_slots (if your optimizer algorithm requires additional variables)
```

However, the current `tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer` implementation does not define a `resource_apply_dense` method, but it *does* define a private-looking [`_resource_apply_dense` method stub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3ba8ba551fc371389d184ba3917cfd826bdefd89/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L916-L928). Similarly, there are no `resource_apply_sparse` or `create_slots` methods, but there are a [`_resource_apply_sparse` method stub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3ba8ba551fc371389d184ba3917cfd826bdefd89/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L958-L977) and a [`_create_slots` method call](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3ba8ba551fc371389d184ba3917cfd826bdefd89/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L434).

In official `tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer` subclasses (using `tf.keras.optimizers.Adam` as an example), there are [`_resource_apply_dense`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b0a5ae9891da8b1c0224a45c2c0130623b9fb1ce/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/adam.py#L192-L227), [`_resource_apply_sparse`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b0a5ae9891da8b1c0224a45c2c0130623b9fb1ce/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/adam.py#L229-L267), and [`_create_slots`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b0a5ae9891da8b1c0224a45c2c0130623b9fb1ce/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/adam.py#L150-L159) methods, and there are no such methods without the leading underscore.

There are similar leading-underscore methods in slightly-less-official `tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer` subclasses (e.g., `tfa.optimizers.MovingAverage` from TensorFlow Addons: [`_resource_apply_dense`](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/999aebc0961ccddb8174cc5331cc23a7291a2255/tensorflow_addons/optimizers/average_wrapper.py#L73-L76), [`_resource_apply_sparse`](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/999aebc0961ccddb8174cc5331cc23a7291a2255/tensorflow_addons/optimizers/average_wrapper.py#L78-L82), [`_create_slots`](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/999aebc0961ccddb8174cc5331cc23a7291a2255/tensorflow_addons/optimizers/moving_average.py#L92-L95)).

Another confounding point for me is that some of the TensorFlow Addons optimizers *also* override the `apply_gradients` method (e.g., [`tfa.optimizers.MovingAverage`](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/999aebc0961ccddb8174cc5331cc23a7291a2255/tensorflow_addons/optimizers/average_wrapper.py#L55-L57)), whereas the `tf.keras.optimizers` optimizers do not.

Moreover, I noticed that the `apply_gradients` method of `tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer` method [calls `_create_slots`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4a7069416442a82270494ec5ad26955e3ff85758/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L434), but the base `tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer` class does not have a `_create_slots` method.
So, it seems that a `_create_slots` method *must* be defined in an optimizer subclass if that subclass does not override `apply_gradients`.

---

## Questions

What is the correct way to subclass a `tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer`? Specifically,

1. Does the `tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer` documentation listed at the top simply mean to override the leading-underscore versions of the methods they mention (e.g., `_resource_apply_dense` instead of `resource_apply_dense`)? If so, are there any API guarantees about these private-looking methods not changing their behavior in future versions of TensorFlow? What are the signatures of these methods?
2. When would one override `apply_gradients` in addition to the `_apply_resource_[dense|sparse]` methods?

---

**Edit.** Opened issue on GitHub: [#36449](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36449)

Comment: This may be something to report as a documentation issue to the devs. It most definitely looks like those methods to override should included the initial underscore in the documentation, but in any case, like you say, there is no information about their signature and exact purpose. It may also be that method names without underscore (and documented) are planned to be added (like with `get_config`), but then they shouldn't yet appear in the [public documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer#write_a_customized_optimizer_2).

Comment: For the signatures, you can always look at the declaration of [`_resource_apply_dense`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.1.0/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L863-L874) or [`_resource_apply_sparse`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.1.0/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L905-L923), and see their usage in implemented optimizers. While it may not be, I think, public API with stability guarantees, I'd say it's pretty safe to use them. They just should provide better guidance in this aspect.

Comment: I agree that this is a documentation issue with TensorFlow. Did you create an issue for this in the tf Github repo? If so, could you share the link here?

Answer (score 7):

**Update**: TF2.2 forced me to clean up all implementations - so now they *can* be used as a reference for TF best practices. Also added a section below on `_get_hyper` vs. `_set_hyper`.

---

I've implemented [Keras AdamW](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/keras-adamw) in all major TF & Keras versions - I invite you to examine [optimizers_v2.py](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/keras-adamw/blob/master/keras_adamw/optimizers_v2.py). Several points:

- You should inherit [`OptimizerV2`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3ba8ba551fc371389d184ba3917cfd826bdefd89/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L79), which is actually what you linked; it's the latest and current base class for `tf.keras` optimizers
- You are correct in (1) - this is a documentation mistake; the methods are private, as they aren't meant to be used by the user directly.
- `apply_gradients` (or any other method) is only overidden if the default doesn't accomplish what's needed for a given optimizer; in your linked example, it's just a one-liner addon to the original
- *"So, it seems that a `_create_slots` method must be defined in an optimizer subclass if that subclass does not override `apply_gradients`"* - the two are unrelated; it's coincidental.

---

- *What is the difference between `_resource_apply_dense` and `_resource_apply_sparse`?*

Latter deals with *sparse* layers - e.g. `Embedding` - and former with everything else; [example](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/keras-adamw/blob/master/tests/test_optimizers_v2/test_optimizers_v2.py#L229).

- *When should I use `_create_slots()`?*

When defining *trainable* `tf.Variable`s; example: weights' first and second order moments (e.g. Adam). It uses [`add_slot()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3ba8ba551fc371389d184ba3917cfd826bdefd89/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L569).

---

[`_get_hyper`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L673) vs. [`_set_hyper`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L656): they enable setting and getting Python literals (`int`, `str`, etc), *callables*, and tensors. They exist largely for convenience: anything set via `_set_hyper` can be retrieved via `_get_hyper`, avoiding repeating boilerplate code. I dedicated a Q&A to it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62042342/10133797).

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, this looks to be a documentation error. The preceding underscore names are the correct methods to override. Related is the non-Keras Optimizer which has these all defined, but not implemented in the base class https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py

```
  def _create_slots(self, var_list):
    """Create all slots needed by the variables.
    Args:
      var_list: A list of `Variable` objects.
    """
    # No slots needed by default
    pass

  def _resource_apply_dense(self, grad, handle):
    """Add ops to apply dense gradients to the variable `handle`.
    Args:
      grad: a `Tensor` representing the gradient.
      handle: a `Tensor` of dtype `resource` which points to the variable
       to be updated.
    Returns:
      An `Operation` which updates the value of the variable.
    """
    raise NotImplementedError()

  def _resource_apply_sparse(self, grad, handle, indices):
    """Add ops to apply sparse gradients to the variable `handle`.
    Similar to `_apply_sparse`, the `indices` argument to this method has been
    de-duplicated. Optimizers which deal correctly with non-unique indices may
    instead override `_resource_apply_sparse_duplicate_indices` to avoid this
    overhead.
    Args:
      grad: a `Tensor` representing the gradient for the affected indices.
      handle: a `Tensor` of dtype `resource` which points to the variable
       to be updated.
      indices: a `Tensor` of integral type representing the indices for
       which the gradient is nonzero. Indices are unique.
    Returns:
      An `Operation` which updates the value of the variable.
    """
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

2. I don't know about `apply_dense`. For one thing, if you do override it, the code mentions that a per-replica DistributionStrategy could be "dangerous"

```
    # TODO(isaprykin): When using a DistributionStrategy, and when an
    # optimizer is created in each replica, it might be dangerous to
    # rely on some Optimizer methods.  When such methods are called on a
    # per-replica optimizer, an exception needs to be thrown.  We do
    # allow creation per-replica optimizers however, because the
    # compute_gradients()->apply_gradients() sequence is safe.
```