# What are _get_hyper and _set_hyper in TensorFlow optimizers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I see it in `__init__` of e.g. [Adam](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.2/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/adam.py#L145) optimizer: `self._set_hyper('beta_1', beta_1)`. There are also `_get_hyper` and `_serialize_hyperparameter` throughout the code. I don't see these in [Keras](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L487) optimizers - are they optional? When should or shouldn't they be used when creating custom optimizers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They enable setting and getting Python literals (`int`, `str`, etc), *callables*, and tensors. Usage is for *convenience* and *consistency*: anything set via `_set_hyper` can be retrieved via `_get_hyper`, avoiding repeating boilerplate code. I've implemented [Keras AdamW](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/keras-adamw) in all major TF & Keras versions, and will use it as reference.

- [`t_cur`](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/keras-adamw/blob/v1.30/keras_adamw/optimizers_v2.py#L110) is a `tf.Variable`. Each time we "set" it, we must invoke `K.set_value`; if we do `self.t_cur=5`, this will destroy `tf.Variable` and wreck optimizer functionality. If instead we used `model.optimizer._set_hyper('t_cur', 5)`, it'd set it appropriately - but this requires for it to have been defined via `set_hyper` [previously](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.2/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L619).
- Both `_get_hyper` & `_set_hyper` enable *programmatic* treatment of attributes - e.g., we can make a for-loop with a list of attribute names to get or set using just `_get_hyper` and `_set_hyper`, whereas otherwise we'd need to code conditionals and typechecks. Also, `_get_hyper(name)` requires that `name` was previously set via `set_hyper`.
- `_get_hyper` enables typecasting via `dtype=`. Ex: `beta_1_t` in default Adam is cast to same numeric type as `var` (e.g. layer weight), which is required for some ops. Again a convenience, as we could typecast manually (`math_ops.cast`).
- `_set_hyper` enables the use of [`_serialize_hyperparameter`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.2/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L861), which retrieves the Python values (`int`, `float`, etc) of callables, tensors, or already-Python values. Name stems from the need to convert tensors and callables to Pythonics for e.g. pickling or json-serializing - but can be used as convenience for seeing tensor values in Graph execution.
- Lastly; everything instantiated via `_set_hyper` gets assigned to `optimizer._hyper` dictionary, which is then iterated over in [`_create_hypers`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.2/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L767). The `else` in the loop *casts all Python numerics to tensors* - so `_set_hyper` will not create `int`, `float`, etc attributes. Worth noting is the [`aggregation=`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.2/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L781) kwarg, whose documentation reads: "Indicates how a distributed variable will be aggregated". This is the part a bit more than "for convenience" (lots of code to replicate).

  - `_set_hyper` has a *limitation*: does not allow instantiating `dtype`. If [`add_weight`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.2/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L960) approach in `_create_hypers` is desired with dtype, then it should be called directly.

*When to use vs. not use*: use if the attribute is used by the optimizer via TensorFlow ops - i.e. if it needs to be a `tf.Variable`. For example, [`epsilon`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.2/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/adam.py#L149) is set regularly, as it's never needed as a tensor variable.